# TextView's text doesn't change?

Tags: android, textview

i'm facing a problem that i never came accross before:
well i successfully applyed the 3D transition between a listview and someother layout container some info about the selected item. well the probelm is: some of the textviews are displayed correctly while others display nothing, even the imageview is shown as expected...

any suggestions?

thanks in advance..

Comment: How are you adding text to the TextViews? Are you using a surfaceView or View?

Comment: i'm just using normal views..it's a textview within a LinearLayout. funny thing another textview within the same LinearLayout is displaying the text correctly..i thought may be i was targeting the wrong id but i checked and everything is fine..

Comment: Could try View.invalidate() if calling from GUI thread or View.postInvalidate() if calling from another thread. Without your code it's hard to make suggestions...

Comment: well i'm working from UI-Thread and already tryed that.. i didn't put any code since it's reaaaly an ordinary code

    myTextView1.setText("......");
    myTextView2.setText("......");
and it works for the first one

thank you anyway for trying^^

Comment: Is the problem occuring on the Emulator or on a real device? Sometimes the emulator can produce problems that don't happen on a real device (in my experience anyway)

Comment: well i'm testing on the emulator right now.. i'll try on a real device..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you had same collision in android:name tags. Acting wierd could happen by many reasons, but one of the most liklly to happen is when you have some collision in names, I mean more views defined with same name

@+id/something definition and @id/something reference is okey
but having @+id/something twice sometimes could be a problem.

This kind of references is usually used in relative layaout when you say I want this view to be to the left (or above, or below) some other view. Then you must give a reference to other view...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this: well i don't know the exact reason but it solved the problem

i changed the textview id in the layout and it worked fine. Weird why it didn't work until this..if any one can explain it would be great^^

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 text view with the same id, one of them is inside the parent layout and the other one was in the viewpager which is child of the parent layout. I changed the latter one is and the problem is solved.